# how to derive a tree from freemarker ftl includes

Tags: include, freemarker

i have ftl A including ftl B and ftl C. And ftl B and C has few more  includes. is there any tool to show the graph/tree of includes?

Answer (score 0):

There's no such tool yet. Though note that as `#include`-s are evaluated on runtime, furthermore the included template name can be dynamic (i.e., it can contain variables), and also the chosen `TemplateTookupStrategy` can complicate things further, it's not in general possible to come up with an inclusion tree without actually executing the template and capturing the `TemplateCache` calls.